# Put an "sort_by" on aws-php-sdk ListObjects

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

In my current project I need to check my S3 bucket contents every 4 seconds for new files.

This script will run for around 3 hours every time that the service is used, and will have something around 2700 files by the end at a single prefix.

This is my function to list those files:

```
public function listFiles($s3Prefix, $limit, $get_after = ''){
    $command = $this->s3Client->getCommand('ListObjects');
    $command['Bucket']  = $this->s3_bucket;
    $command['Prefix']  = $s3Prefix;
    $command['MaxKeys'] = $limit;
    $command['Marker']  = $s3Prefix.'/'.$get_after;

    //command['Query'] = 'sort_by(Contents,&LastModified)';

    $ret_s3 = $this->s3Client->execute($command);

    $ret['truncated'] = $ret_s3['IsTruncated'];
    $ret['files'] = $ret_s3['Contents'];

    return $ret;
}// listFiles
```

What I do need is get the files, order by the LastModified field, so I do not need to fetch over 2k files.
Is there an extra parameter like

```
command['Query'] = 'sort_by(Contents,&LastModified)';
```

to add in the php API?

**---------- EDITED ------------**

As pointed for Abhishek Meena answer, in the shell it is possible to use

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "bucket-name" --prefix "some-prefix" --query "Contents[?LastModified>=\`2017-03-08\`]"
```

What I'm looking is how to implement this in PHP.

PHP API: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they have some thing to sort the objects on the bases of `LastModified` but you can query and filter objects on the `LastModified` column.
This is what you can use to filter all the files modified after certain time `` aws s3api list-objects --bucket "bucket-name" --prefix "some-prefix" --query "Contents[?LastModified>=\`2017-03-08\`]" ``

This is for the shell they might have something similar for the php.

Comment: Yeah, from the shell documentation that I tried something like command['Query'] = 'sort_by(Contents,&LastModified)'. The something similar is what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: Since all this is getting converted to the same API definition. You can try this and check `command['Query'] = "Contents[?LastModified>=$date";` where $date will contain your datetime as mentioned in the [aws-sdk-php](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#listobjects) result section. **'LastModified' => <DateTime>**